# Setting variable's value using its memory address

Tags: arrays, vb.net, memory

I have a BIG problem with vb.net (I don't like it -I'm more a vb6 fan).
       I want to create a "3DGraphics" class and I want that when someone creates some vertexes and loads them into memory he'll get an address of the location where the vertexes are (simple said: the address of the vertexes array-**I know how to take the address** using VarPtrArray). 
      Then the user can take the address and pass it to a sub from the class named "RotateScene" which will rotate every point by a given angle. The problem is I don't know how to access the array's elements using the passed address. I searched a little on google and I couldn't find anything concrete. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: What does "XY problem" mean?

Comment: See: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/246262)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using a pointer to an array is that you would need to fix the array in memory so that it can't be moved by the garbage collector. That means that you can't just get the pointer and use it on its own, you can only use it inside a block of code where the array is released afterwards.

Intead of using a pointer, just use the reference to the array. In VB.NET the array won't be copied when you pass it around, so you can just send the array reference to a method that alters the array. The method doesn't get a copy of the array, it gets a reference to the array, so when it changes the array items that's done in the original array.

Example:

```
' Create an array
Dim vertexes(1) As Double
' Then put something in it
vertexes(0) = 1.0
vertexes(1) = 2.0

' Just pass the array normally
RotateScene(vertexes)
' When the method returns the array items has changed
```

Method:

```
Public Sub RotateScene(vertexes As Double())
  ' Change the array items in here
  vertexes(0) = 2.0
  vertexes(1) = 1.0
End Sub
```

Comment: You're talking about byref? Can you provide me with some code?

Comment: @sergiureznicencu No, Guffa is referring to reference types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: @sergiureznicencu: You only need `ByRef` if you need to replace the array itself, to change the items in the array you pass it normally (`ByVal`). I added an example above.